# Invalid keyword Port

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string, remote-server

**connection string** :

```
 <add name="connectionstringname" connectionString="server=XX.XX.XXX.XXX; port=XXXX; Database=databaseName; user id=UserID; password=password;"
    providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Is working fine on my machine but when I commit change to the live server, It gives error as 
**"Invalid keyword Port"**

**Note** Database is on the different server and I am using same from local and live server

Comment: Does the live server have the MySql connector driver installed?

Comment: yes. also i m providing the driver reference in my application with copying the driver

Comment: Are you able to connect when you specify the connection string in code vs your config file?

Answer (score 0):

try to use notation like this:

```
server=XX.XX.XXX.XXX:YYYY .....
```

where YYYY is your port number.

Comment: its gives error me on local machine.... and the database server i am using same from local and online

Comment: and also what can be the reason its working on local and not on the server?